# Why does data from Ajax w XMLHttpRequest not arrive to the div id indicated

Tags: ajax, xmlhttprequest

I seem to have a very specific problem where something is missing and I just can't see it.
From and index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Untitled Document</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="./js/a1.js"></script>
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="./js/a2.js"></script>
        <style>
        </style>
    </head>
    <body onLoad="javascript:Scan()">
        <div id = "TheDiv">?
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

From onLoad, I call Scan()

```
function Scan()
{
    divResultado = document.getElementById('TheDiv');
    //instanciamos el objetoAjax
    ajaxScan=objetoAjax();
    ajaxScan.open("GET", "myscan.php", true);

    DBScan = setTimeout(Scan,15000 );

    ajaxScan.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if (ajaxScan.readyState==4)
        {
            //mostrar resultados en esta capa
            divResultado = ajaxScan.responseText;
        }
    };
    
    ajaxScan.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    ajaxScan.send( );   
}
```

myscan gets data from a database and in debug, I see that information is properly transfered to divResultado above.

But the data doesn't appear in the div with id = "TheDiv"

I've done this hundreds of times before, but something somwhere has made itself
invisible to me.

In the raw data HTML, I think it appears below and outside of the  context.

What am I not seeing

Answer (score 0):

Because you're not writing the data to the page, you're just assigning it to a variable:

```
divResultado = ajaxScan.responseText;
```

Which means `divResultado` no longer refers to the element on the page, it now refers to the text from the AJAX response.

To set the text to that element, try:

```
divResultado.innerText = ajaxScan.responseText;
```

Or, if the result is HTML:

```
divResultado.innerHTML = ajaxScan.responseText;
```